# powerapp button submit email when clicked

Tags: email, button, sharepoint, click, send

I created a powerapp that links to a sharepoint list which contains a list of expired laptops. I need help creating a button within the app that will remove the item from the sharepoint list and send an email containing the users name and details from the list (laptop make, model, serial number etc...)